# Flutter import package:sqfite not reconize

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hi everyone I'm starting to learn mobile cross-platform development with flutter. But right now I'm stuck at sqlite dependency. Can anyone help please!! thank you for your time.

[import picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z2qk.png)

[dependencies picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtmOX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove extra space. Please see the below example.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

My solution:
go to https://pub.dev and search lib you want.
open terminal and input

```
flutter pub get <lib>
```